# starting activity from itself skips the OnCreate

Tags: android, oncreate

I have this activity which is called `MainPutShipActivity` and I want to start it again so it will do the same thing but it doesn't even enter the `OnCreate` method.

here is the `MainPutShipActivity`:

```
public class MainPutShipActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private static final int MAX = 10;
private String name1,name2;
private Player plr = new Player();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_put_ship);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    plr = (Player) intent.getSerializableExtra("player");
    name1 = plr.getName1();
    name2 = plr.getName2();

}

public void finished() {
    Intent in;
        }
    if (plr.isTreated() == false) {
        plr.setArr1(arr);
        plr.setShip1(ships);
        this.finish();
        in = new Intent(this,MainPutShipActivity.class);
        in.putExtra("player", this.plr);
    }
    else {
        plr.setArr2(arr);
        plr.setShip2(ships);
        in = new Intent(this, MainGameActivity.class);
        in.putExtra("player", this.plr);
    }
    plr.setTreated(true);
    this.finish();
    startActivity(in);
}
```

When i enter the `finished()` procedure for the first time it suppose to start the `MainPutShipActivity` again but when it starts the activity, it skips the onCreate and goes straight to the finished() method for some reason.

I would be very glad for any kind of help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Comment: post your second activity code.

Comment: Maybe you can use parcelable, please check this link http://androcode.es/2012/12/trabajando-con-parcelables/

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to the key passed in the intent

Instead of :

```
plr = (Player) i.getSerializableExtra("plr");
```

set

```
plr = (Player) i.getSerializableExtra("player");
```

because you are setting

```
in.putExtra("player", this.plr);
```

Comment: It is still doesn't work. I believe it doesn't even reaching to this point and crashes in the `finished()` procedure , although i can't see what is the problem.

Comment: what is the logcat of the crash?? Check if your plr is not null

Comment: What is line 44? I'm not sure of the i = getItent(); outside the onCreate

Comment: Try  plr = (Player) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("player");

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know what it was but you helped me a lot.